# Excel vba Next invoice number with creation of automatic directory folder by month

Tags: excel, vba

Ok , here is the thing,
I have created a next invoice number program in which by pressing of a macro assigned button active invoice automatically saved and closed and the next invoice with a number increased appear.My problem is that, I want excel invoices to be created in their relevant folder by their first two digits of invoice number . as an example : 04-001 where 04 stands for April. also, when invoice number is given 05-002,  the directory folder of may 2018-19 should be auto created and invoice should be there in the folder only. i am trying to figure out the code since some time but no luck till now. So far , The invoices are created according to date only but as darren said it is a problem for me when i am trying to create invoices from december on first day of january.

This is my current code :

```
Sub SaveInvoiceM()
    Dim NewFN As Variant
    If Len(Dir("C:\Invoices\" & Format(Date, "MMM YYYY") & "-" & (Format(Date, "YY") + 1), vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir "C:\Invoices\" & Format(Date, "MMM YYYY") & "-" & (Format(Date, "YY") + 1)
End If
    ' Copy Invoice to a New Workbook
    NewFN = "C:\Invoices\" & Format(Date, "MMM YYYY") & "-" & (Format(Date, "YY") + 1) & "\Inv" & Range("F5") & ".xlsx"
    ActiveWorkbook.saveas NewFN, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
    NextInvoice
End Sub
```

Range("F5") stands for my invoice number which is 04-001

Comment: ***Okay, here's the thing:***  this isn't a "free code writing service", plus I don't see a "question" in your question.  [so] is a place that developers (of any experience level) can bring a *specific* question about a *specific* issue, ***share their existing code*** and explain (as best as possible) what's been researched & tried so far, along with examples of what they have and what they "need to have". See [mcve] and [help/on-topic] as well as [these tips](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/writing-the-perfect-question/).  You can [edit] your question to explain where you're at.

Comment: _the directory folder of may 2018-19_ - how does it know the year?  You could take the current year, but on the 2nd January when you're processing invoices for the end of December.   Otherwise - as ashleedawg said, can you show what you've tried please?  For a starter `MonthName(4)` will return April.

Comment: Hi , Darren , I have re-edited the question. And you have guessed the issue right.

Comment: Dear Ashlee , I hope you have something to share to solve my problem with the code .

Comment: Use a @ and the user name when you want to get someones attention - Ashlee won't get a notification of your comment unless you refer to him as @ashleedawg. How will you deal with the invoices being made the following month?  A cell with the year in?  Change the invoice number to include the year?  All invoices in January will be for December?

Comment: @Jeet can you simplify?  `when invoice number is given 05-002, the directory folder of may 2018-19 should be auto created` . How would it know the year?  Do you want to use the current year?  If so, what happens if it's January 1, 2020 and you're working with an invoice from the previous day? Still use 2020?

Comment: I see what you're trying to do here and I've seen many people have great sounding plans of auto-organizing documents into folders by month/year etc, but it always turns out being more of a pain than it's worth, since there are better ways to organize.

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes , you are getting it right . The directory of may 2018-19 should be auto created and is being created already , just look at my code and u will understand . The year is automatically adjusted according to computer's date and time . What my problem is when i am trying to create bill in the month of january they automatically goes to jan folder , so i want a code that can generate a code according to first two digit of my invoice number.  As eg : 05-002 where 05 stands for may .

Comment: i don't think you get what I mean.  I will write an answer with a suggested solution a little different than you have in mind.

Comment: How would it know the year :? 
The answer is in the code . "C:\Invoices\" & Format(Date, "MMM YYYY") & "-" & (Format(Date, "YY") + 1). 

Do you want to use the current year ? 
Yes and it is being used already.

If so what happens if it's january 2020 ..... ?
It will automatically adjust to 19-2020 or i have to modify the vba code each year manually and set it to 2018 - 19 instead of my current formula.  It would be "C:\Invoices\" &  "2018." & "-" & "19". 

However i am looking forward to see your answer if i am missing your any point .

Comment: Will whatever day today is always be assigned to the file ? 
Yes and sometimes i am creating my december bill in january 2nd so they should be go to the folder of dec 2018-19 instead of january . @ashleedawg

Comment: ok, got it.  And are these invoices you are *receiving* from elsewhere, or are you *creating* them?  (What I'm getting at there is, do you have any control over changing the invoice number?)  It will make more sense in the end if you include the year in the filename too, at the beginning, like today, your 49th invoice: "1803-49" with a filename of "1803-49.xlsx".

Comment: Yes, only i am generating them no one else .

Comment: You'll notice I'm not the only one seeing a potential problem with the year. (@DarrenBartrup-Cook brought it up too)  We've all been down this road and deciding on a number scheme should be done very carefully.  What you include and in what order makes a big difference later on.

Comment: So , bill created in december will have sequence like 12-001 . When they are created in january as i go with =today() , the created bills  automatically generated to january folder . So i have come up with solution if i put first two digit of my invoice number in the vba and defined it as month then it wouldnt be a problem whatever the date is .

Comment: alright.. I'm putting something together for you. (I'm kind of a data geek so I have a thing for organized numbering systems!)  Oh and one more question: I assume these invoice numbers you're giving them are sequential, right?  The first invoice of the month is 001, the next one you do is 002....003...004 .  always in order when you're creating them, I assume?

Comment: I'm almost done but just had a thought:  based on your line `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`) i gather this will be a "template" that you open up for each new invoice, fill in whateever, and then this files "saves a copy of itself"( with a new name) correct?  Because if so, you can't save it as an `XLSX', it would have to be `XLSM`. Is that okay? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Yes , the invoice number are in sequences. And yes xlsm is correct if one is going to use any macros . As for me xlsm do just fine and i was only playing with xlsx format .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to do (keep nicely organized, automatically) and that's an excellent goal.

I have a suggestion of an alternate invoice numbering system (based on what I'm understanding of your situation & experience level) that will make tasks (like this "auto-filing" process) much easier, and will also simplify the process any time you (or especially anyone else) needs to look back at these invoices.  There are a number of obvious benefits (same idea as *metric vs imperial*).

---

**Ideal numbering system:**  *(in my opinion)*

1. To reduce confusion: Give each invoice **and** filename the ***same name*** instead of having a filename with a month and
2. Since you want granularity from months to years (but not days): make the invoice/file name include the all of those fields.
3. To make sorting & finding these logical (easier): place each "date part" in order of biggest to smallest.  A unique sequential number goes at the very end.

---

Your code sample was a good start - I just have a bit of OCD when it comes to this kind of thing, and creation of a numbering system is an important task.  (Also this will be "date-proof", and error-checked along the way...

This is a little different than what you had because **instead of you telling the code what the next invoice number is, it tells you** (by figuring out the next number in sequence based on the existing files).

Like yours, it creates a folder if necessary.  Since the files are number `YYMM-nnn` then are always in the correct order when you *sort them*. (The "month folders" are unnecessary since the month is in the filename, but I included them anyway since that was your plan.  You could just keep every month's invoices in one folder, and they'd still be organized in order of month.)

---

## VBA #1: Save file with next sequential invoice number (creating folder if necessary)

```
Sub createInvoiceNumberAndSave()
    'creates a new invoice number based on date in specified cell & creates new folder if necessary
    'finds next unused invoice number & verifies that file is properly saved

    Const invoicePath = "c:\invoices\"  ' invoice root save path
    Const fNamePrefix = "Inv"           ' prefix for the filename
    Const fNameExt = ".xlsm"            ' file extension
    Const getInvoiceDate = "F5"         ' we GET the DATE of the invoice from F5
    Const putInvoiceNumber = "F6"       ' we will PUT the new filename into cell F6

    Dim invDate As Date, folderName As String, fName As String, fNum As Long, nextInvoiceNum As Long

    'get the invoice date and make sure it's valid
    If IsDate(Range(getInvoiceDate).Value) Then
        'valid date found in cell F5
        invDate = Range(getInvoiceDate).Value
    Else
        'valid date not found in F5. Do we want to default to today's date?
        If MsgBox("Cell " & getInvoiceDate & " does not contain a valid date." & vbLf & vbLf & _
            "Do you want to use today's date instead?", vbQuestion + vbOKCancel, "Date not found") <> vbOK Then
                Call MsgBox("Invoice Not Saved.", vbCritical + vbononly, "User Cancelled")
                Exit Sub 'stop running
        Else
            invDate = Date 'use today's date
        End If
    End If

    'find the next unused invoice number for this month
    folderName = Format(invDate, "YYMM")
    nextInvoiceNum = 0

    'figure out the next unused "file number"
    fName = Dir(invoicePath & folderName & "\" & fNamePrefix & folderName & "-*" & fNameExt)
    If fName = "" Then
        'file not found
        If Dir(invoicePath & folderName, vbDirectory) = "" Then
            'month not found - create folder?
            If MsgBox("Okay to create folder '" & invoicePath & folderName & "' for invoice #" & folderName & "-001 ?", _
                vbOKCancel + vbQuestion, "Folder not Found") <> vbOK Then Exit Sub
            'create folder
            MkDir (invoicePath & folderName)
        End If
    Else
        'month found. Now find the highest invoice number in the folder.
        Do While fName <> ""
            Debug.Print "Found File: " & fName
            'get the number (filename = fNamePrefix & "YYMM-___.xlsx" so we know where it is
            If IsNumeric(Mid(fName, 6 + Len(fNamePrefix), 3)) Then 'it's a valid number
                fNum = Val(Mid(fName, 6 + Len(fNamePrefix), 3))
                'if it's the biggest so far, remember it
                If fNum > nextInvoiceNum Then nextInvoiceNum = fNum 'biggest one so far
            End If
            fName = Dir
        Loop
    End If

    'we have the next available invoice#
    nextInvoiceNum = nextInvoiceNum + 1 'new invoice# (numeric)
    'PUT the new invoice# (text) in cell F6
    Range(putInvoiceNumber).Value = fNamePrefix & folderName & "-" & Format(nextInvoiceNum, "000")
    fName = invoicePath & folderName & "\" & Range(putInvoiceNumber).Value & fNameExt
    Debug.Print "Saving as: " & fName

    'save file
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName

    'DOUBLE CHECK check that file exists (couple lines of code now save a headache later)
    If Dir(fName) = "" Then
        'something went wrong (file wasn't saved)
        Call MsgBox("ERROR! FILE NOT SAVED: " & fName, vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "ERROR!")
        Stop
    End If

    'success message!
    Call MsgBox("Invoice saved successfully:" & vbLf & vbLf & fName, vbInformation, "Invoice Created")

    'NextInvoice '?

End Sub
```

---

**EDIT: *("Back to your way")***

I can think of a number of ways that your method *will* be a problem, some of which I tried explaining, but you're determined to number & organize these files your way, so "here you go".

## **VBA #2: Save file with cell value as name:**

This procedure saves the current file, named from the invoice number (like `04-001`) that you enter in cell `F5` (creating folder if necessary):

```
Sub SaveFileBasedOnInvoiceNumber()

    Dim monthNum As Long, yearString As String, folderName As String, fName As String

    'build filename
    On Error Resume Next 'skip errors for now
    monthNum = Val(Left(Range("F5"), 2))
    yearString = Year(Date) & "-" & Right(Year(Date) + 1, 2)
    folderName = "c:\invoices\" & StrConv(monthName(monthNum, True), vbUpperCase) & " " & yearString
    fName = folderName & "\INV" & Range("F5") & ".xlsm"

    'check if there was a problem
    If Err Then MsgBox "Invalid invoice number": Exit Sub
    MkDir (folderName) 'create folder
    On Error GoTo 0 'turn error checking back on

    'Confirm file saved properly
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fName 'save file
    If Dir(fName) = "" Then MsgBox "Error! File not saved: " & fName: Exit Sub
    MsgBox "Invoice saved successfully:" & vbLf & fName

End Sub
```

I'll leave "**VBA #1**" in the the top of the answer for others seeking a logical numbering & storage system with auto-generated invoice numbers.

<sup>(One day you'll figure out why that way would've been better, but be forewarned, it will be a lot more of a hassle to change your organization method later!)</sup>

Good luck!

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg,
Many thanks for the help, however,
There is one Major thing that need to be modified is:
Invoice numbering format should be remained 04-001 where 04 is suggesting month and 001 is sequential number through out a year. 
Folder name of each month should be like: APR 2018-19, MAY 2018-19
rather than taking the date as a source of creation to folder month wise, i want to use first two digit of invoice number which can be 04,05,06 to determine the month as i will be inserting them manually every month. only sequential number "-001" is increased continuously through out a year.

Comment: So major focus is first two digit of invoice number will determine in which month the invoice will be saved as i will be inserting them manually .

Comment: alright, I added a second code block to my answer but will leave the first one in case you change your mind (possibly around January).  Good luck!

Comment: Hi @ashleedawg Thank you so much for your help . As for the year goes , I have come up with an Idea to adjust the code once a year . Something like this :

`code` Dim MyInv, MyMonth, MyYear, MyDate, MyFormat
    MyInv = Range("F5").Value
    MyMonth = Left(MyInv, 2) + 0
    MyYear = 2018
    MyDate = DateSerial(MyYear, MyMonth, 1)
    MyFormat = Format(MyDate, "MMM YYYY") & "-" & (Format(MyDate, "YY") + 1)
    MsgBox MyFormat `code`

Also sequential number will always be unique ... 001-,002,003 ...

Comment: Yes , in your code I tested Yearstring = "2018 - 19" and its working great .  There will always be concern regarding the year once it changes so better to set it manually and change once a year. anyways thank you so much once again for providing great help.